# I copy the files that the gatsby build gives to ampps/www/my-site but the links not work

Tags: reactjs, apache, gatsby, ampps

I create a new site using the gatsby-cli. Then I just build the site, then, all the content that is inside the `build` I copied to my `AMPPS/www/my-site` folder. When I access to the site, the index works correctly but when I click on a route to go to another route I got the following error: `The requested URL /page-2/ was not found on this server.`.

I understood that gatsby will generate an static HTML site, and the production server where I need to place the build only accepts an static HTMl site. So is there a way to achieve a truly server side rendering with gatsby?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple:

If apache serves ampps/www/my-site as http://localhost/my-site you need to use path-prefix, by default gatsby assume it will be hosted at root of domain.

To enable this features, we just need to use the following documentation: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/